# Stuck on extracting title and next page url from pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to extract the link of each rv unit detail page in these search results as well as the next page of search results so I can get the links to every rv unit they have on there [site](https://rv.campingworld.com/searchresults?condition=new_used&custompricerange=true&custompaymentrange=true&sort=featured_asc&zipsearch=true&search_mode=advanced&locations=nationwide)

```
import scrapy

class cwscrape(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rvlinks'

　　start_urls = ['https://rv.campingworld.com/searchresults?condition=new_used&custompricerange=true&custompaymentrange=true&sort=featured_asc&zipsearch=true&search_mode=advanced&locations=nationwide']

　　def parse(self, response):
    　　for rvname in response.xpath("//div[@class='title']"):
        　　yield{ 'rv_full_name':　rvname.xpath(".//span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract_first()}

    　　next_page= response.xpath(".//div[@class='pagination-wrap']/a/@href").extract_first()
    　　if next_page is not None:
        　　next_page_link= response.urljoin(next_page)
        　　yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

Example url for each detail unit would be:
 https://rv.campingworld.com/rvdetails/new-class-c-rvs/2019-thor-freedom-elite-26he-front-living-60k-BKY1571461

Next page url would be:
https://rv.campingworld.com/searchresults?condition=new_used&custompricerange=true&custompaymentrange=true&sort=featured_asc&zipsearch=true&search_mode=advanced&locations=nationwide&scpc=&make=&landingMake=0&page=2

Comment: What is the issue? Have you tried debugging the scrapper?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code in `scrapy shell` and everything looks fine:

```
In [5]: response.xpath("//div[@class='title']//span[@itemprop='name']/text()").extract()
Out[5]: 
[u'2019 THOR FREEDOM ELITE 22HEC',
 u'2018 THOR GEMINI 23TR',
 u'2018 THOR GEMINI 23TK',
 u'2019 THOR FREEDOM ELITE 24HE',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO MINNIE WINNIE 22R',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO MINNIE WINNIE 22M',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO OUTLOOK 27D',
 u'2019 THOR FREEDOM ELITE 28FE',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO MINNIE WINNIE 25B',
 u'2019 THOR FREEDOM ELITE 28FE',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO OUTLOOK 31N',
 u'2019 THOR QUANTUM RC25',
 u'2018 THOR SYNERGY JR24',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO MINNIE WINNIE 26A',
 u'2019 THOR QUANTUM KM24',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO MINNIE WINNIE 31G',
 u'2019 THOR SYNERGY 24SJ',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO VIEW 24G',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO VIEW 24V',
 u'2019 WINNEBAGO OUTLOOK 22E']

In [6]: response.xpath(".//div[@class='pagination-wrap']/a/@href").get()
Out[6]: u'https://rv.campingworld.com/searchresults?condition=new_used&custompricerange=true&custompaymentrange=true&sort=featured_asc&zipsearch=true&search_mode=advanced&locations=nationwide&scpc=&make=&landingMake=0&page=1'
```

What kind of problem did you meet?

Comment: Thank you I was looking at the json file output and it didn't have the next link in it.

Comment: But the next link should not be there :) You're calling request of this link.